# extending magento ACL

Tags: user-roles, role, acl

I was tasked with extending Magento ACL functionality and allowing one user to hold more than one role.

I have been jumping from blog to blog and file to file for the last week - all I can find says only about isAllowed() method - this is nothing to do with what I'm looking for.

Why? If I log all calls to isAllowed() I get different results for admin and user - system already knows for which resources isAllowed() must be called.

I'm trying to create additional tables that holds user_id and role_id
ACL would be combine for all your roles.

I'm looking for a place in code when ACL matrix is contracted:
I narrowed my suspects to:

**/app/code/core/Mage/Admin/Model/Resource/Acl.php**

```
loadAcl();
loadRoles();
loadRules() ( $acl->allow() and $acl->deny() )
```

but I couldn't find any user-specific queries or methods 
How system know you can access resources or not?
Am I looking in the right place?

**Also:**
checking files I found this comment:

```
//@FIXME: stupid fix of previous multi-roles logic.
```

in **/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php** saveAction() aprx. Line 142

Looks like that functionality was available in previous versions - is there any existing code I could use?

Thank you in advance for any info that can help me to move that forward.

Best Regards,

Comment: It'll probably be quicker just to create the roles are the supersets of the roles you want to combine. Looking at that FIXME is a dead end, it's over 5 years old https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-mirror/blob/d19f0e13d3d2fcbcc2d8fa6073568d5f95442470/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Permissions/UserController.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have made a breakthrough today.

In fact isAllowed() is the only method to override. The reason why I was getting different numbers of calls for admin and user was because first time function isAllowed() is called is to find first available url - you can access in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php setIsFirstPageAfterLogin()

In fact if you override isAllowed() like this:

```
public function isAllowed() {
    return true;
}
```

You will get access to all resources.

Thank you for your comment Richard!